# Java 8 - Optional class on List of Objects

Tags: java, java-8

I have an `ArrayList` of `Car` objects. I'm checking for null values and for `Germany` and doing something inside an `if` condition.

But I want to use `Optional` class to avoid checking for null. How can I use it?

Here is my code:

```
public class TestOptional {

    public static List<Car> getCarList() {
        List<Car> carList = new ArrayList<Car>();
        carList.add(new Car("Benz", 2016, "Germany"));
        carList.add(new Car("Rolls Royce", 2015, "Russia"));
        carList.add(new Car("BMW", 2017, null));
        carList.add(new Car("Maruti", 2014, ""));
        return carList;
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        List<Car> carList1=getCarList();
        for(Car c:carList1) {
            if(c.getCountry() != null && c.getCountry().equalsIgnoreCase("Germany")) {
                System.out.println(c.getCarName()+" car is from Germany");
            }
        }

        Optional<Car> optional = getCarList();
    }
}
```

I am getting this error:

```
`Type mismatch: cannot convert from List<Car> to Optional<Car>`
```

I am not sure how to use the `Optional` class on a `List` of objects.

Please find my Car code :

```
public class Car {

    private String carName;
    private int year;
    private String country;

    public Car(String carName, int year, String country) {
        this.carName = carName;
        this.year = year;
        this.country = country;
    }

    public String getCarName() {
        return carName;
    }

    public int getYear() {
        return year;
    }

    public String getCountry() {
        return country;
    }



}
```

** Update 1 **

I was started exploring some Java8 Features and i found `Optional` class and i want  to use it. I found the usages of `Optional` class.

> *In Java 8, we have a newly introduced Optional class in java.util package. This class is introduced to avoid NullPointerException that we frequently encounters if we do not perform null checks in our code. Using this class we can easily check whether a variable has null value or not and by doing this we can avoid the NullPointerException.*

So, i tried to apply Optional class for my ArrayList and i want to avoid null checking for all of my objects in my ArrayList.

```
List<Car> carList1=getCarList();
    for(Car c:carList1) {
        if(c.getCountry() != null && c.getCountry().equalsIgnoreCase("Germany")) {
            System.out.println(c.getCarName()+" car is from Germany");
        }
    }
```

In the above code, i checking for null for Country Object. So here i want to avoid writting null check code (using Optional Class).

Comment: An `Optional<Car>` contains **zero or one** cars. Your list contains **four** cars. What is the  `Optional<Car>` supposed to contain?

Comment: If I understood right, are you trying to avoid null check for `country`?

Comment: Why are you expecting a `List<Car>` to change to `Optional<Car>`? According to your question it is something inside the `Car` that needs to change (return `Optional<String>` for the `getCountry()` for example? You haven't put the `Car` code in your question.

Comment: @Thiru - Yes i want to avoid null check on country

Comment: A good way to deal with this is to make it impossible to create a Car with a null country in the first place, by putting this in your constructor:  `this.country = Objects.requireNonNull(country, "Country cannot be null");`

Comment: Unless there is more than this one comparison, you could just do the comparison like this: `"Germany".equalsIgnoreCase(c.getCountry())`, then it won't matter if country is null or not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is generally not recommended to use `Optional` with collections. You can perfectly represent no results with an empty collection.

What you really want is to change your `Car` to avoid returning `null` countries.
So inside your `Car` where you have `String getCountry()` change it to:

```
Optional<String> getCountry() {
  return Optional.ofNullable(country);
}
```

Then inside your loop you can do:

```
c.getCountry()
 .filter(country -> country.equalsIgnoreCase("Germany")
 .ifPresent(country -> System.out.println(c.getCarName()+" car is from Germany"));
```

You can also use a `Stream` instead of a `for` loop if you like.

```
getCarList()
       .stream()
       .filter(this::isGerman)
       .forEach(car -> System.out.println(car.getCarName()+" car is from Germany");
```

Where the function `isGerman()` is this:

```
boolean isGerman(Car car) {
  return c.getCountry()
     .filter(country -> country.equalsIgnoreCase("Germany")
     .isPresent();
}
```

Comment: Well the question is not really clear (why were you trying to put a list of cars into an `Optional`?) and doing some research would have led you to the answer. There are hundreds of articles about how to use Java 8 `Optional`, it is not something complicated. Probably that is why people gave you down votes.

Comment: I have updated my expectation on `Optional` class in my question. Could you please suggest me on this.

Comment: @Karthikeyan Not sure what your question is, you just pasted the Javadoc. I showed you in this answer how to use it. If there is a possibility that `country` is `null` (some cars do not have a country?) you do not return `String` but return `Optional<String>`. `Optional` then offers methods to use it in a functional way, like `map()`, `flatMap()`, `filter()` and `ifPresent()`.

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like this to check weather you have a car matching your condition. Not sure if this is what you're asking though.

```
Optional<Car> carOptional = getCarList()
                           .stream()
                           .filter(Objects::nonNull)
                           .filter(c -> c.getCountry() != null && c.getCountry().equalsIgnoreCase("Germany"))
                           .findFirst();
```